# Assign controls with view iOS, Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, xib

i have a problem is there any way to make something like outlet in my custom UIView class. I connect view with class via

```
class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "AddressView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }
```

my whole class looks like

```
class AddressView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        var view = AddressView.instanceFromNib()
        self.addSubview(view)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        var view = AddressView.instanceFromNib()

        self.addSubview(view)
    }

    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "AddressView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect IBOutlets from Storyboard if AddressView is subclass of UIViewController and you make your xib of class AddressView (selecting AddressView as custom class from the Identity Inspector of your xib File's Owner)